# Firebase - userId keeps changing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In an Android project I use Firebase with `signInAnonymously()` and I am getting `userId` like this

```
userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

and I use the userId to create children nodes in `Firebase Realtime Database` that only this user can access based on the access rules of that database.

The problem is that I noticed userId changes randomly and when that happens all content created by that user is lost to them. Is there something I can do to keep the same userId until the app is uninstalled? What other way can I use to ensure steady and exclusive access for that user to a Realtime database child? Can installation id be used?

Comment: This is the default behavior is using signInAnonymously().

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez yes but that doesn't help with the question

Comment: You could probably use `createUser/signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and generate a random email and password but the user would still need to use the required login details on an uninstall. My understanding is that if you want persistent data and accounts, you need to partially authenticate a user. `signInAnonymously()` should be used for `read-only` apps, if I understand it right.

Comment: I had this issue. deleting the app and re-installing it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Anonymous Authentication to create and use **only** temporary accounts to authenticate with Firebase. The Anonymous Authentication accounts don't persist across application uninstalls. When an application is uninstalled, everything that was saved locally will be wiped out, including the anonymous auth token that identifies that account. So there is no way you can reclaim that token for the user. So each time you sign in, a new UID is generated.

> What other way can I use to ensure steady and exclusive access for that user to a Realtime Database child?

To always have the same UID, then you have to implement the Firebase Authentication with a provider like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and so on.

Comment: I understand that. But the problem is that userId changes across app launches...not installs. I would be happy if it stayed the same until the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: The userId changes across app launch **only** if you explicitly sign in again. Otherwise, it will always remain the same. So most likely there is something wrong with your code. So I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?